# asp.net url minus pagename and querystring

Tags: asp.net, url, path, httprequest

I've been looking around the web for a simple and straight forward solution for the following problem but I cant seem to find anything that suits my needs.

I have an asp.net site with many subdirectories as follows.

- http://mysite.com/dir1/subdir1/
- http://mysite.com/dir1/subdir2/
- http://mysite.com/dir2/
- http://mysite.com/dir3/subdir1/

etc...

On each of my sites pages I need to extract the URL to the page minus the pagename and querystring.

So if the page name was http://mysite.com/dir1/subdir2/mypage.aspx?param=5&param2=9

I would need the following http://mysite.com/dir1/subdir2/ I cant find any properties of the httprequest object that make this URL format readily available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're right, such thing is not ready so you need to make it yourself. One recipe is:

```
public string GetSubFolderURL()
{
    string url = "http";
    if (string.Equals(Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"], "ON", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        url += "s";
    url += "://";
    url += Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
    int port;
    if (Int32.TryParse(Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"], out port) && port != 80)
        url += ":" + port;
    url += Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"];
    return url.Substring(0, url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/dfdb20ae-b335-48ae-a201-f2a5a8329342/How-Do-I-Get-Paths-and-URL-fragments-from-the-HttpRequest-object.aspx). It should give you everything you need, especially `Url.Segments`.

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(url).Replace(@"\","/");
```